# Does networkx give maximum depth (or nesting depth)?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, depth-first-search, depth

I am using networkx to build graphs for a project.For a specific plot I need max depth (or nesting depth) of each node (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499017/know-the-depth-of-a-dictionary)).

For eg.

I have multiple nodes in my graph, say-

`G -> d, foo, bar, tar, zar, car, char, jar, par, radar, far, ....`

where `d` is connected with others like this,

`d -> {'foo': {'bar': {'tar': 2}, 'zar': {'car': {'char': 1}, 'jar': 'par'}}, 'radar': 'far'}`

I want max depth (or connectivity) of nodes.

So, in this case -
`d->foo->zar->car->char` (5 nodes in total)

Is there any way to calculate this using networkx (I have over 1M nodes, so the data is huge!)?

I checked their manual [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html).

Also checked different posts online but couldn't find the information.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people coming to your question can help you address it better.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I just updated my question and tried to provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't.

So, I edited their [github](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) code to add this functionality.

Code:

```py
max_d = []

#dfs_depth base Code reference networkx

def dfs_depth(G, source=None, depth_limit=None):
    if source is None:
        nodes = G
    else:
        nodes = [source]
    visited = set()
    if depth_limit is None:
        depth_limit = len(G)
    for start in nodes:
        print(start)
        if start in visited:
            continue
        max_depth = 0
        visited.add(start)
        stack = [(start, depth_limit, iter(G[start]))]
        while stack:
            parent, depth_now, children = stack[-1]
            try:
                child = next(children)
                if child not in visited:
                    yield parent, child
                    visited.add(child)
                    if depth_now > 1:
                        if((depth_limit - depth_now + 1)>max_depth):
                            max_depth = depth_limit - depth_now + 1
                        stack.append((child, depth_now - 1, iter(G[child])))
            except StopIteration:
                stack.pop()
    global max_d
    max_d.append(max_depth)
```

Here `max_d` keeps track of the maximum depth (or nesting depth). To calculate the maximum depth of each node, a loop can be used (which iterates through all the nodes).