# Depth of tree without class using recursion

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, binary-tree

Given 4 trees in a dictionary form:

```
tree0 = {} 

tree1 = {'L': {}, 'R': {}, 'V': 3} 

tree2 = {'L': {'L': {}, 'R': {}, 'V': 2}, 'R': {'L': {}, 'R': {'L': {}, 'R': {}, 'V': 6}, 'V': 1}, 'V': 5}

tree = {'L': {'L': {},  'R': {'L': {'L': {}, 'R': {'L': {'L': {}, 'R': {'L': {}, 'R': {}, 'V': 9}, 'V': 4}, 'R': {}, 'V': 13}, 'V': 2}, 'R': {}, 'V': 8}, 'V': 3}, 'R': {'L': {}, 'R': {'L': {}, 'R': {}, 'V': 6}, 'V': 1}, 'V': 5}
```

How can I make a function `depth_t(t)`, that takes as argument one of the trees above, that determines the depth of the tree recursively, without using a class?
I have been struggling with this. The only thing I got was:
`if len(t)==0: return 0`
Can somebody give me some tips?

The depths of all trees above are:

tree0 depth 0

tree1 depth 1

tree2 depth 3

tree depth 7

tree['L'] depth 6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Know the depth of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499017/know-the-depth-of-a-dictionary)

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and we cannot simply "give you some tips" on an assignment because *we have no idea why you aren't able to solve it yourself*. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm feeling that this is a homework question, I will give you a hint: if you were somehow able to get the depth of the left and right children of a tree, then how would you combine them to calculate the depth of the tree? Say we have `depth_right` and `depth_left`. what would be the expression calculating the total depth? Once you know that, and since the left and right children are *smaller instances* of the problem, you can call the function recursively on the left and right children to calculate `depth_left` and `depth_right` and the problem is solved.