# Can we use for loop to iterate over a dict of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict of nested dicts and key-values.

```
 dicta = {'key1': {'keya': 'a', 'keyb': 'b'},
      'key2': {'key3':{'keyc': 'c'}}, 'key4': 4}}
```

Is there a way I can use a for loop to get to 'c'?

I tried,

```
print(dicta['key2'])

for x in dicta['key2']:
    for y in x['key3']:
        print(y)
```

For the first print, I get

```
{'key3': {'keyc': 'c'}}
```

But I get TypeError: string indices must be integers for the second print.

Thanks in advance!
*I edited replacing n with dicta; I copied and pasted it wrong the first time.

Comment: It doesn't look like you should be *iterating* here. You probably just want `dicta['key2']['key3']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. Dicts can be arbitrarily recursively deep, and there's no good way to traverse them using nothing but a `for` loop. (You could implement your own stack using a list and simulate recursion, but that's not "good".)

There's some recursive code for traversing dictionaries (counting the depth) in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538875/recursive-depth-of-python-dictionary)

In specific, sure. Knowing the structure in advance, you can use the right number of `for` loops:

```
n = {'key1': {'keya': 'a', 'keyb': 'b'},
     'key2': {'key3':{'keyc': 'c'}}, 'key4': 4}

for k1,v1 in n.items():
    try:
        for k2,v2 in v1.items():
            try:
                for k3,v3 in v2.items():
                    print(v3)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: What is the standard way to traverse them, not using a for loop?

Comment: A stack (depth first search), a queue (breadth first search), or simulating either of those with recursion.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in somedict` is to loop all the keys from a dictionary.
See more details from [dict views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)

> When looping through dictionaries, the key and corresponding value can
>   be retrieved at the same time using the `items()` method.

[items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs).
So you can just try this:

```
for k,v in dicta['key2'].items():
    if isinstance(v,dict):
        for k1,v1 in v.items():
            print(v1)
```

`isinstance(v,dict)` return true if the object argument is an instance of the `dict` argument,so you don't need to catch exception.

Have a look at [looping-techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to dive into given dictionary and print the key and its values.

```
def drill(dicta):
  for k in dicta.keys():
    if isinstance(dicta[k],dict):
      drill(dicta[k])
    else:
      print ('dicta[',k,']=',dicta[k])
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in n:
    v = n.get(k)
    if isinstance(v, dict):
    for j in v:
        print(v.get(j))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loop you can get the required results.

```
for k,v in dicta.items():
     if k=="key2":
         new_dict=v
         for k1, v1 in new_dict.items():
               print v1["keyc"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.